# UML Designer discards undefined types

Tags: uml, uml-designer

When I type a method signature, UML Designer discards all unknown types, e.g., if you add class `FooBuilder` to an empty class diagram, and then type the following signature:

```
setBar(b: Bar): FooBuilder
```

`Bar` will be discarded and the signature will be set to:

```
setBar(b: ): FooBuilder
```

Is it possible to disable such behaviour, i.e., make UML Designer accept the types that aren't defined yet (maybe, automatically define them)?

Answer (score 1):

That would be an interesting feature to create automatically a class for unknown types. Could you create a new issue in the bug tracker: 
https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/new ?

Comment: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/964

That would be a feature that speeds up input of methods quite a bit in most cases, as the users won't have to go through lots of input dialogs to add a single method.